# reading from plist issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a plist which is an array, the file name is called startups.plist. I tried to read it into an array by the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"startups" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray * wordList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

However, wordList is always 0 here. Printed the path when testing on device, and it gives me:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/CCBF94D9-389C-4D63-B023-F39653FDCEF4/My.app/startups.plist
```

Here's what the structure looks like of the plist:

[image]

the size of the array is 0.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the value (and contents) of `path`?

Comment: I've had it above right.. it's that var/mobile/Applications/,,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initWithContentsOfFile:` will not open plist file. Here is a sample:

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString    *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"startups" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData      *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization                     
                                          propertyListFromData:plistXML
mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                          format:&format
                                          errorDescription:&errorDesc];
NSLog(@"%@",[temp objectForKey:@"Root"]);
```

Comment: awesome! thanks... I was reading a tutorial and they use initWithContentsOfFile

Comment: You are welcome. If you use `initWithContentsOfFile` method of `NSDictionary` it might open it, but I prefer this method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `NSDictionary` since your plist is a Dictionary which has a key Root which is an array.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"startups" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableArray *wordList = (NSMutableArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"Root"];
```

I'm not sure about casting to `NSMutableArray`. Maybe you have to do

```
NSMutableArray *wordList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)[dict objectForKey:@"Root"]]
```

Comment: That's incorrect. "Root" is not a dictionary key, it just indicates the root object in the property list.

Comment: If I'm trying to recreate this structure the XML of the plist looks like this:
    <dict>
        <key>Root</key>
        <array>
            <string>one</string>
            <string>two</string>
        </array>
    </dict>